# Redis encryption of data at rest

Tags: encryption, redis, persistent-storage

Is there a way  to automatically encrypt the data 'at rest' in a redis cache database, like there is in SQL server, for example? (so I am talking about the data itself, not the transport of the data)
If not how would one go about encrypting the data?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not for the stand alone version.  If you are using Redis Enterprise on a cloud computing platform, there are options.

https://docs.redis.com/latest/rc/security/database-security/encryption-at-rest/

Answer (score 1):

Since Redis is an in-memory data store, so you shouldn't really need to worry about data at rest as it is not being persisted anywhere. You will however need to, if you have enabled persistence or write the data or RDB file to disk or other storage. In that case perhaps your disk could be encrypted or storage could be encrypted as well.

Comment: I think we should worry about it. The fact that it is short-lived can still make it vulnarable over a longer period of time

Comment: Redis does save data to disk by default as a recovery measure. Keeping it all in memory doesn't mean never writing to disk. https://redis.io/topics/persistence.